# Finding second-order finite difference stencil

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

If you have the anisotropic diffusion equation to find $u(x,y)$

$$\left(\mu_{x}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}+\mu_{y}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}}\right)=f(x,y) \tag 1$$

and you discretize the problem using second-order finite difference formulas, leading to the discretized form:

$${-\mu}_{x} \left(\frac{u_{i-1,j} - 2u_{i,j} + u_{i+1,j}}{h^2}\right) - {\mu}_{y} \left(\frac{u_{i,j-1} - 2u_{i,j} +
u_{i,j+1}}{h^2}\right) = f_{i,j} \tag 2$$

How do you calculate the finite difference stencil $S$ corresponding to this finite difference scheme?

$ S = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
s_{11}&s_{12}&s_{13}\\ 
s_{21}&s_{22}&s_{23}\\
s_{31}&s_{32}& s_{33}
\end{bmatrix} \tag 3$

Comment: This is not the diffusion equation. This is the orthotropic Poisson equation. Also, your second equation is inconsistent with the first one so I will edit it.

Comment: May I suggest you watch this video on YT, where the Laplace equation is solved using the finite difference method? It is thoroughly explained: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWCNVF9oMkw

Comment: @NikolaRistic Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think he speaks of how the stencil is calculated?